# GridView Items have massive margins at the top and bottom, also not being refreshed when using invalidateViews()

Tags: android, image, gridview

I've been trying to get a GridView to work nicely in order to display a undertermined number of images. There's no text, just images which are loaded from a local file using picasso from an adapter.

I've had to extend the default GridView due to the wrapping issue where it only displays one row, this is the XML for the GridView:

```
<com.company.app.component.PictureGridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image_gallery"
            android:layout_below="@+id/unused_checkbox_holder"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center"/>
```

This is how I'm setting the adapter:

```
File[] files = getPictures();
imageGalleryView.setAdapter(new ImageGalleryAdapter(getContext(), files));
```

And the finally the extended BaseAdapter class:

```
public class ImageGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

List<Items> itemList;
String[] data;

Context context;
File[] files;

private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;


public ImageGalleryAdapter(Context context, File[] files){
    this.files = files;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(files == null){
        return 0;
    }
    return files.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ImageView imageView;

    if(convertView == null){
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
    }else{
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(files[position])
            .noPlaceholder()
            .into(imageView);
    return imageView;

}
```

}

Now this works aside from three major parts, firstly there is a massive margin on each item to the top and bottom which makes the whole view massively oversized, this can be fixed by using the resize function in picasso but it's a fix per device not for everything.

Secondly, calling:

```
imageGalleryView.invalidateViews();
```

Doesn't seem to do anything, it doesn't refresh the gridview, this is called right after a camera activity is finished saving an image so there is definitely a new image to be displayed, it displays the new image after the fragment is closed and reopened however.

Third and finally, landscape images completely screw this whole thing up, they look nice and cleanly spaced in portrait but a single landscape causes the following images to be shifted out of place with their boundaries going all over the place.

Comment: Image is captured and stored in your folder but your file array is still having old images not new one. so after successful camera work just make a call for getPictures(); to update your existing files array and then make notifyDataSetChange()

Comment: I updated my answer please take a look

Comment: @ReadyAndroid I had a go at what you said and posted the result in Teck Wei's answer below

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem that exactly how image view work. You need to use `ScaleType` to make the image nicer if you it will just try to present the whole image inside imageview. Use piccaso resize is a very good way and you can try to use center crop with it. So when you using picasso you don't have to worry your first and third problem it get solved.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(files[position]).noPlaceholder().centerCrop().resize(200,200).into(imageView);
```

I don't get the meaning of this line.

> using the resize function in picasso but it's a fix per device not for everything.

Please also note when your image is too big it might be a big problem when you scroll the gridView.You may find a very heavy scrolling so just use the piccaso resize function which also help u to memory cache the resize image.

For your second question use this

```
imageGalleryView.notifyDataSetChange();
```

Update

```
ImageGalleryAdapter adapter = new ImageGalleryAdapter(getContext(), files);
```

Try to create seperate adapter and you can use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Alright I've tried the two parts you suggested, the centerCrop() part works great and has fixed issue three for me, and mostly fixed issue one, there's still a somewhat large margin on really tall and thin screens but it's good enough for the moment.

Comment: However, the second part still doesn't refresh it, even if I update the Files array I can't call notifyDataSetChange, the only function I can call which is similar is deferNotifyDataSetChange().

Comment: @CarlingKnight okay after any photo taken from your app you need to insert the picture you taken into the file array. As long as your file array your norificationDataSetChanged will not work. And upload your first problem image becuz i really cannot understand what is urs problem.

Comment: And try to make base adapter to inflate from xml file rather than create the view inside it is kinda bad pratice.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's exactly the best way to go about it, but I found that updating the files array and then simply setting the adapter again achieves the desired effect quite nicely!

Comment: Okay I found your Problem see update code I update now

Comment: For your first problem i really need image